# How to set the size of an image in a Word document from RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have an RMarkdown document like this with markdown for multiple images stored in a dataframe, and I am outputting them in a table in a Word document.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r}
my_data_frame <- 
  data.frame(images = c(
    "![](https://www.r-project.org/Rlogo.png)",
    "![](https://www.r-project.org/Rlogo.png)"
  )
)

knitr::kable(my_data_frame)
```
````

The images show fine, but I want to make them bigger. I don't seem to be able to.

I have tried

`[](https://www.r-project.org/Rlogo.png {width=250px}`

I have also tried setting:

`knitr::opts_chunk$set(out.width="400px", dpi=120)`

But the images sizes never change. How can I control the image size?

Comment: There's a space between `...jpg` and `{width=250px}`, have you tried removing that specific space?

Comment: Thanks @Matt yes I tried that but no difference Im afraid